# Db2 to MongoDB Migration

Tags: java, mongodb, db2, database-migration, data-migration

I am new to MongoDB and planning to migrate DB2 data (~6TB) to Mongodb. In MongoDB we having some schema changes(not one to one /direct mapping) so we are planning to use Java to migrate the same.

Options I am thinking of:

1. Read the data from DB2 and insert the same in MongoDB using Java
   threads
2. Read the data from DB2 and convert to a BSON file using Java
   threads, store on disk and then use mongo import tool to load
   data into Mongodb.

Which option is best to migrate the data from db2 to Mongodb (other than tools)?

Please guide me here!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1.Read the data from DB2 and insert the same in MongoDB using Java threads

I think this would be the best option. I am also working for DB2 to mongo DB migration

Comment: Seems like total record is very high still option 1 will work?
If you have any sample java code for this migration, kindly share the same?